# Merging Objects Succinctly as Parameters in Function

Tags: javascript

I have a function that takes in two objects as parameters, and then compares those two objects, recursively, to produce a new object. I am now setting up some tests for this function. If I want to add a node to the root of one of the objects, on the fly, in a succinct way, I can do this:

```
diff(oldObj, {...newObj, testRootProp: 'testValue'});
```

My question is, is there a succinct way I can add a node to the object when the node I want to add to is not at the root?

For instance, say I want to take this object:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "John"
  associates: [
    {name: "Samantha"},
    {name: "Jonah"},
  ]
}
```

And produce this:

```
{
  id: 1,
  name: "John"
  associates: [
    {name: "Samantha"},
    {name: "Jonah", member: false}, // this has changed
  ]
}
```

Is there a succinct way I can do that with my `diff(oldObj, newObj)` function, making this change on the fly by what I pass in, rather than having to pass the entire new object as the second parameter?

Comment: i dont see how to answer to your question without to see your diff function? but you are completely chnages the structure of json..so i doubt its easy to do that

Comment: Not sure why that would be the case. My `diff(oldObj, newObj)` function takes in two objects as parameters, and produces a new object as a result. All I want to know is if there is a succinct way I can pass in a changed second object as the second parameter in the function.

Answer (score 1):

You could add a parameter to diff, which would specify where on the target object to put the extra value.

```js
const location = {
  name: 'Arbys',
  hours: {
    monday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
    tuesday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
    wednesday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
    thursday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
    friday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
    saturday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
  },
};
const newLocation = diff(
  location,
  { open: "10:00 AM", close: "9:00 PM" },
  { path: 'hours.sunday' }
);
// newLocation
// {
//   name: 'Arbys',
//   hours: {
//     monday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     tuesday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     wednesday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     thursday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     friday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     saturday: {open: '8:00 AM', close: '10:00 PM'},
//     sunday: { open: "10:00 AM", close: "9:00 PM" },
//   },
// }
```

Your example is tricker because you need to change something inside an array.

```js
const person = {
  id: 1,
  name: "John",
  associates: [
    {name: "Samantha"},
    {name: "Jonah"},
  ],
};
const newPerson = diff(
  person,
  false,
  {
    path: '[associates].member',
    finders: [
      (node) => node['name'] === 'Jonah',
    ],
  }
);
```

The third param specifies how to place the new `false` values. It says:

1. At the top level of the target object, there is an array called `associates`.
2. Use the first function in the `finders` array to find the object(s) we want to add to.
3. Add a `member` key to the found object(s) with the value `false`.

In this way, you can specify any place on the target object to place the new value.

```js
const college = {
  students: [ /* ... */ ],
  // ...
};
const mutatedCollege = diff(
  college,
  { name: 'Randy', id: '12345' },
  {
    path: '[students].[courses].professor',
    finders: [
      (student) => student.isFullTime,
      (course) => course.hours > 3,
    ],
  },
);
```

Of course, the caller can still omit the third param and just merge the objects:

```js
const a = {foo: 'x');
const b = {bar: 'y');
const c = diff(a, b);
// c
// {
//   foo: 'x',
//   bar: 'y',
// }
```

Comment: This is a good idea, but in my case I'm not at liberty to add a 3rd parameter. It all has to be passed in according the original function definition: which is two parameters, one for each object to compare. I could still work something like this, but I'd have to break out a new function to define the second object separately, and then pass that into the `diff(oldObj, newObj)` function.